# How do I show complex symmetry properly?

Tags: matrices, inner-products, complex-geometry, symmetry, self-adjoint-operators

> Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be such that $A = A^{*} $ and $<x,Ax> > 0$ whenever $x \ne 0$.
> We define $$\forall u,v \in \mathbb{C}^n: (u|v) := <u,Av>$$ where $<.,.>$ is the standard where the first argument should be complex conjugated. Prove that $(u|v)$ is an inner product.

So, I have to show positive definiteness:
Let $u \in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $u \ne o$. By definition the following holds:
$$(u|u) = <u,Au> > 0$$
and if $u=0$:
$$(u|u) = <u,Au> = 0$$
Now I have to show linearity:

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u,x,v \in \mathbb{C}^n$, then:
$$ (au+bx,v)= <au+bx,Av>= <au,Av> + <bx, Av> = a<u,Av> + b<x,Av> = a(u|v)+b(x|v)$$

Now, I have to show complex symmetry but I am not sure how to show complex symmetry here. Could anyone show me how to show complex symmetry in detail? I think I have to use he fact that $A=A^*$ somehow but I am not quite sure how it should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=A^*$ means that for all $u,v$, you have $$\langle u,Av \rangle = \langle Au, v \rangle$$

Therefore,
$$(u|v)=\langle u, Av \rangle = \langle Au, v \rangle = \langle v, Au \rangle = (v|u)$$

Comment: I have to show that (u|v) = (v|u) by the definition of the standard inner product. So $(u|v)=<u,Av> = u^*Av = (Av)^*u = A^*v^*u= <A^*v,u> = <Av,u>= (v|u)$, something like that?

Comment: Hmm what does $*$ mean ?

Comment: Complex conjugate of $u$ since the first argument has to be complex conjugated or so like if we had vectors with real entries, you would have: $<x,Av>= x^T * Av$. Could you show me the whole step to prove the symmetry? At the end I have to show (u|v) = (v|u). I think it would be really helpful to see what you are thinking.

Comment: Hmm but by definition, if $A=A^*$, then $\langle u,Av \rangle = \langle Au, v \rangle = \langle v, Au \rangle $ so you don't need to use the definition of the standard inner product.

Comment: Oh, if you could edit your answer with the whole step one has to write down to properly show the symmetry, I would really appreciate it and mark your answer!

Comment: This is done :)

Comment: Thank you very much :)